# Почему NaN? React

Tags: reactjs

Мне нужно сделать сумму exercises в компоненте Total, но показывает NaN

```
import React from 'react'
    
const Total = (props) => {
    return(
        <>
            <p>Number of exercises {props.numOfExercises.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
               return previousValue.exercises + currentValue.exercises;
            })}</p>
        </>
    )
}
    
export default Total;



import React from 'react'
import Total from "./components/Total";

const App = () => {
    const course = 'Half Stack application development'
    const contentText = [
        { part: 'Fundamentals of React', exercises: 10 },
        { part: 'Using props to pass data', exercises: 7 },
        { part: 'State of a component', exercises: 14 }
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            <Total numOfExercises={contentText} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: После первой итерации reduce вторая итерация будет в `previousValue` содержать результат первой итерации — число 10+7=17, а у чисел не бывает никаких exercises, поэтому `previousValue.exercises` это `undefined` и `undefined + 14` это получается `NaN`

Comment: @andreymal а если я меняю так {props.numOfExercises.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
               return previousValue.exercises + currentValue.exercises;
            },0)} чтобы для первой итерации было значение 0 то это тоже не меняет ничего.

Comment: Ну так причина та же самая: в первой итерации previousValue это число 0, а у чисел не бывает никакого exercises, поэтому previousValue.exercises это undefined и undefined+10 это тоже NaN и далее по аналогии

Comment: @andreymal поняла, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
<p>Number of exercises 
{props.numOfExercises.reduce(
    function(previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue + currentValue.exercises;
    }, 0)
}</p>
```

Comment: Я попробовала сделать так с вашей подсказки и получилось! 
<p>Number of exercises {props.numOfExercises.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
                return previousValue + currentValue.exercises;
            },0)}</p>

спасибо вам!

Comment: Исправил спс извините

Comment: @puzzelena Пометьте ответ галочкой, если данный ответ является решением вашей проблемы